# English translation of Ganesh Sahasranam

Tags: puranas, translation-request, ganesha

Any interpretation and translation available in English for Ganesh sahasranam as in the ganesha purana? Wikipedia mentions of a khadyota commentary by bhaskaraya on the sahasranama. Is there an English translation available for this commentary?

Comment: I haven't come across any in English yet.

Comment: Found one audio that chant verse with commentary and explanation in English at [here](http://www.mywhatever.com/Sanskrit/gsn/index.html). Click on verse number provided in tabular form to hear.

Comment: @Pandya, Have seen this before too. It has only up to 230 names explained.I had emailed the author but could not get any response. In fact the very beautiful names are coming towards the end. Thanks

Comment: Xbert please link the SahasraNaama.

Comment: Check [this one](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/thousand-names-of-ganesha-sanskrit-text-transliteration-translation-IDF979/)